# Does relativization of formulas replace bounded quantifiers or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let $\phi$ be a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) and $a$ be a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)). The *relativization* $\phi^a$ of $\phi$ to $a$ is defined as the formula obtained by replacing all [[unbounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier#Bounded_quantifiers_in_set_theory)?] [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) $Qx$ in $\phi$ by $Qx {\in} a$. I sometimes see the definition that replaces all quantifiers, bounded or unbounded. However, I sometimes see the definition that replaces only unbounded quantifiers. For example:

- Reference 1 (p. 60):

  > $C^z$ is obtained from $C$ by replacing all unbounded quantifiers $\exists x$ in $C$ by $\exists x \in z$.
- Reference 2 (p. 833):

  > For every $\mathrm{L}_\Omega$ formula $A$ we write $A^\sigma$ to
  > denote the $\mathrm{L}_\Omega$ formula which is obtained by replacing
  > all unbounded quantifiers $(Q \xi)$ in $A$ by $(Q \xi < \sigma)$.
- Reference 3 (p. 29-30):

  > Here $\Phi^M$ is the formula obtained from $\Phi$ by replacing all unbounded quantifiers of the forms $\forall x, \exists x$ by quantifiers $\forall x \in M, \exists x \in M$. [...]
  > \begin{align}
  > (\forall x \Phi)_M &= \begin{cases}
  > \forall x \Phi_M & \text{$\Phi$ is of the form $x \in a \to \Psi$} \\
  > \forall x {\in} M \Phi_M & \text{otherwise}
  > \end{cases} \\
  > (\exists x \Phi)_M &= \begin{cases}
  > \exists x \Phi_M & \text{$\Phi$ is of the form $x \in a \land \Psi$} \\
  > \exists x {\in} M \Phi_M & \text{otherwise}
  > \end{cases}
  > \end{align}
- Reference 4 (p. 10):

  > If $A$ is a transitive set and $\phi$ is a formula with parameters in $A$ we denote by $\phi^A$ the formula which arises from $\phi$ by replacing all unbounded quantifiers $\forall u$ and $\exists v$ in $\phi$ by $\forall u \in A$ and $\exists v \in A$, respectively.
- Reference 5 (p. 33):

  > Further, we write $A^\sigma$ to denote the $\mathcal{L}_\Omega$ formula which is obtained from $A$ by replacing all unbounded stage quantifiers in $Q \tau$ in $A$ by bounded stage quantifiers $(Q\tau \prec \sigma)$.

Which of the two definitions is correct? Is one more prominent or common than the other? Is there a standard notation and/or terminology for each that distinguishes the two?

---

References:

1. [*The art of ordinal analysis*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.385.1088). Michael Rathjen. 2006.
2. [*Some theories with positive induction of ordinal strength $\phi \omega 0$*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275787). Gerhard Jäger, Thomas Strahm. The Journal of Symbolic Logic. Volume 61. Issue 3. September 1996. Pages 818-842.
3. [*Large sets in constructive set theory*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30267838.pdf). Albert Zieger. The University of Leeds School of Mathematics. December 2014.
4. [*Proof theory of constructive systems: inductive types and univalence*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02191). Michael Rathjen. 5 January 2018.
5. [*On Feferman’s operational set theory OST*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007207000784). Gerhard Jäger. Annals of Pure and Applied Logic. Volume 150. Issues 1-3. December 2007. Pages 19-39.